# How to extract all Dropbox users' folders/files information by API?

Tags: api, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am using Dropbox API v2 and .NET. I was able to connect to our Dropbox business.

When I do a list of folders/files, it will return them under my account only and that makes sense.  However, I would like to extract all members' folders/files information (name, path, users).  I have a team admin permission.

Does anyone have an idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: Via [Team member file access API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/business)?

Comment: I guess I can extract all the member information.  Then I can "sign-in" as to extract his/her data ... ?

Comment: @orhtej2
I would like to extract all the users who are external (not a member) as well ...

Comment: @golfhajime This post may be helpful: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-Support-Feedback/How-to-get-all-the-files-and-folders-of-a-business-account/m-p/281630/highlight/true#M17242 
Note that this only enables access to members of the Business team. You can't list the contents of other accounts that aren't on the team without authorization.

Comment: @Greg - Thank you, Greg.  

So you suggest to get members' info, connect to Dropbox as per user and get list of files/folders, right?

About external users ..  I don't have any external user account.  Just need to get external users' name/email if they are in shared folders.

Comment: @golfhajime Yes. For shared folders and shared folder members, check out [/2/sharing/list_folders](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-list_folders)[[/continue](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-list_folders-continue)] and [/2/sharing/list_folder_members](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-list_folder_members)[[/continue](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-list_folder_members-continue)].

Comment: @Greg - thank you for your quick reply!  I extracted all the members' team member ids and account ids.  But I am not sure how I can use those ids to access user account (to get folders' information). Dropbox-API-Select-User?  Do I need to use BeginGetAccount/EndGetAccount to change current account?  I am using .NET.

Comment: @Greg - Never mind.  I was so off.  I just pass team member id to AsMember function to get the client, and then run GetCurrentAccountAsync.  It's working nicely.  Thank you for your guidance!!!

Answer (score 0):

It was fairly simple.  Something like this ..
(c#)

```
private DropboxTeamClient DBTeamClient;
private DropboxClient DBClient;
...

var members = await DBTeamClient.Team.MembersListAsync();
foreach (var member in members.Members.OrderBy(a => a.Profile.Email))
    {
    var userClient = DBTeamClient.AsMember(member.Profile.TeamMemberId);
    var list = await userClient.Files.ListFolderAsync(string.Empty);
    foreach (var item inlist.Entries.OrderBy(a -> a.PathDisplay))
    {
        ...
```